# What are the advantages if we wake up before Sun-rise according to Vedas?

Tags: scripture

what are the advantages if we wake up before sunrise according to our scriptures.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Suryavanshi means "**Descendant** of Surya" not one who gets up before sun rise.

Comment: There are advantages to waking up before sunrise, but as @Surya  said it has nothing to do with the word Suryavanshi.  Suryavanshi refers to the members of solar dynasty, who are descendants of Surya's son Vaivasvaya Manu.  Rama was a solar dynasty king.

Comment: So I suggest you take out the Suryavanshi part and just ask about the advantages of waking up before sunrise.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan It looks like you pointed me instead of Surya.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Thanks, I fixed it.  That's one of the perks of being a moderator, I can edit a comment long after it's been posted.

Comment: It is not so much the waking up, it has more to do with japa and meditation. There is a certain calmness to the world at the hours of sunrise and sunset and man has a predominance of sattva at those hours. It is easiest to put the mind into a meditative mood at those times. The hour before sunrise is sometimes referred to as the hour of Brahman. It is the easiest time to attain deep meditation.

Comment: One of the reasons why it is recommended to wake up around 3 or 4 A.M is because of bad dreams. After 4 A.M, people get those dreams which should be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Humanity's relationship with nature is unbreakable. We depend on her for everything -- sunshine, rain, food, air, clothing and more. Hence it is imperative that her laws 
are not flouted. The one and a half hours just before sunrise is known as Brahmamuhurta. At this time the expanse of the sky will have a rosy-red hue. A few stars may 
also be visible. This sacred interval is also known as the Amritavela. This is the best time to get out of bed and meet the day. All the birds and animals that Mother 
Nature has assigned to awake at this time are indeed up by then. Hence they are able to enjoy the sacred bliss of those pristine moments during the Amritavela.

> कुचेलीनं दान्तामलोपचरिनं । भवाशीनं निष्टुरभाशीनं च ।।
>
> सूर्योदयेच स्थमितां शयनं ।। विममुच्चती श्री यदी चक्रपाणी ।।

**Kuchelinam dantamalopacharinam ,Bahvashinam nishthurabhashinam cha
Sooryodaye chastamite shayanam , Vimunchati sreer yadi chakrapanih**

On the other hand, those who arise at this time will experience increased health, strength and spiritual lustre. The following verses from the ancient Hindu text, 
 **Atharva Veda (9.68.22)**, makes it clear that "Bathing in the rays of the rising sun at this time will destroy many illnesses."

> उदायांनित्य रश्मीहिभी: शिर्षणोहो: रोगाः निनाश: ॥

**"Udyannaditya rashmibhih seershno rogamaneenashah."**

Obviously the meaning here is that the rays of the rising sun have certain special qualities that are not found in the sunrays at other times. 
**"Atharva Veda"** **अथर्ववेद** describes the curative power of the rays of the rising sun:

"The rising sun removes all the factors which cause death." (17.1.30).

"The rosy rays of the rising sun cure heart disease and paleness." (17.1.30).

These are some examples. Similarly, the **Rig Veda ऋग्वेद,**  text, also describes how the rising sun dispels all heart disease and jaundice **(Rig Veda 1.50.11).**

The scriptures exhort us to sit facing the east at sunrise, to perform worship (sandhya) and a fire sacrifice (homa). The **Srimad Bhagavata**, the gold mine of devotion,
Says that the main means of acquiring health through worship of the sun is the surya namaskara. ("Arogyam bhaskaradichhet.) The surya namaskara is also to be performed 
facing the sun. **All this can be completed only if we wake up before dawn.**

> ब्राह्ममुहूर्ते उत्तीहीष्टेथ । स्वस्थो रक्षःमायूषः ।।

**Brahme muhurte utthishteth
Swastho raksharthamayushah**

**(Ashtangahridaya: Sutrasthana)**

Comment: I think "उदायांनित्य रश्मीहिभी: शिर्षणोहो: रोगाः निनाश: ॥" means "the rising sun rays are capable to destroy diseases...."

Comment: Looks like this answer is taken from http://archives.amritapuri.org/matruvani/vol-01/jul01/01mv07dawn.php but I see no citation. Plagiarism is against SE rules. See [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: @ sv , Yes you are quite correct , thanks for letting me know that " "Plagiarism is against SE rules." I am well aware of this , and also with disadvantages of  copy-paste rules. I fully appreciate your concern. Well for starters and novice person like me , at least for some time their is a need for take readymade ref. from outside source. As I will get more familiar with BASICS in some future , my ability  to give answers without some support will get improved .So this copy paste method is for short time only . Well anyway Thanks again .

Comment: Refer this post [The copy-paste issue, Hinduism version](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48/the-copy-paste-issue-hinduism-version) and also don't place space between "@" and username. And also edit and mention the source of information else we have to take it down.